# Having trouble setting up FTP server on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ftp

I set up the ftp server to allow anonymous access. It seems that something is wrong with the directory permissions. When I try to use Filezilla to access the server, I get a 530 error.

`530 User anon@localhost cannot log in, home directory inaccessible.`

I modified the access permissions of the ftp folder, so it can be read from anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like one or more of:
1. The home directory doesn't exist. It will not create the home directory for you.
2. The user, either anonymous (IUSR_Server) or your account (whichever is used to login), doesn't have traverse directory permission to the home directory.
3. The IP is not allowed to log in (either not allowed with the 'block all except' setting, or blocked with the 'allow all except' setting).

Answer (score 2):

You can follow [this guide](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/windows-server-2008-ftp-iis7/2008-04-25/) to setup anonymous FTP in Server 2008.

Are you sure that you specifically allowed anonymous read/write access?

-Josh

*Edit - There is another SF question very similar to yours--[linky](https://serverfault.com/questions/128348/iis7-windows-server-2008-ftp-response-530-user-cannot-log-in)